# Generate HTML issues reports from Sonarlint commandline for C# projects

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I'm trying to generate HTML issues report for my C# projects using Sonarlint for the command line. After downloading and following instruction from [Sonarlint command line page](http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline),  I still can't generate c# reports (even when I copied c# plugin to plugins folder) but it works fine with Java projects.

My question is: can Sonarlint create C# html issue report? If it can't, is there any alternative way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarLint for Command Line can't be used on Java, C#, VB/Net, C/C++ projects because the analysis of those projects requires to be fully integrated into the build systems. So for C# and VB.Net, the only but powerful way to get a feedback while coding is by using SonarLint for Visual Studio (http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!